# Forwarding from Controller to Razor Component won't work

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Radzen Upload Widget and I'd like to reload the page after the file from the upload widget was processed in the controller:

The `NOWDeals.razor` which forwards the file to the Controller:

```
 @page "/Goodwill/NOWDeals"

<RadzenUpload Url="upload/single" Style="margin-bottom: 20px;"
              Progress=@(args => OnProgress(args, "Single file upload")) Complete=@OnComplete ChooseText="Datei hochladen">
</RadzenUpload>
```

In the controller, the file is being processed (transferred to a database) and after this is done, I'd like to reload the NOWDeals component

```
public class UploadController : Controller
    public IActionResult Single(IFormFile file)
    {
    // Processing the file
     return RedirectToPage("/Goodwill/Pages/NOWDeals");
    }
}
```

I want to forward to the NOWDeals page after the processing in the controller:

[image]

I have tried these combinations:

```
RedirectToPage("/Goodwill/Pages/NOWDeals");
RedirectToPage("/Goodwill/NOWDeals");
RedirectToPage("/NOWDeals");
RedirectToPage("NOWDeals");
```

But none of these work. The error i get is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No page named '/Goodwill/NOWDeals'
> matches the supplied values.

I also tried `return Redirect("/Index");` which gives me a meaningful console log:

> [15:56:56 INF] Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /Index.

But the browser is not refreshing/forwarding to the Index page.

Comment: A razor file is not a Razor Page - it is a Razor component, so maybe you need a different redirect? (sorry not sure which - hence this is not an answer)

Comment: Good point, I changed the headline of this post.

Comment: It was obviously a bad point - I'm not sure RedirectToPage is the right command as they are not "Pages"

Comment: I tried return Redirect("/Index"); which gives me a positive console log [15:56:56 INF] Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /Index. ---- but nothing happens in the browser.

Comment: Show the code that is hitting the controller?

Comment: I've added some more code to the original post. In the meantime, I figured out how to solve my problem by using the onComplete method in the NOWDeals.razor instead of an explicit Forward in the controller. However, it would still be good to know if tbhere is a solution for that problem.